# How to make the video play only when netstream is done loading

Tags: actionscript-3, video, load, duration, netstream

I noticed that the play() function of netstream is a mix of loading and playing.
But I just want to load it,not to play it.What can I do?

I have tried setting the buffertime same as the duration of the video.
It didn't work out well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the bytes loaded equals bytes total repeatedly. If they equal, remove the listener/stop the interval and play the video.

Comment: Yea but the pause function stops the downloading... how can i pause only the vid?

Comment: How can it stop the downloading? That's not supposed to happen.